# Security implications of providing an encryption/decryption oracle

Tags: encryption, aes, web-service

I need to provide a service that acts as a symetric encryption/decryption blackbox :

- the box get a secret key `k`
- users send datas `d`, and get ciphertext `c = Encrypt(d,k)`
- users send ciphertext `c`, and get data `d = Decrypt(c,k)`
- the box should encrypt/decrypt only from/to an authorized set of users
- users should never get the key `k`

I am having a little trouble identifying what could be holes in my service. As far as I understand, I need crypto that resist the following attacks :

- Choosen Ciphertext Attack
- Choosen Cleartext Attack
- Know plaintext attack

On a technical view, encryption/decryption is done using AES, which is believed to resist to the said attack. With an HMAC, I should able to refuse requests coming from unauthorized users.

Is it true that ;

- a user will not be able to find the key despites the fact he can encrypt/decrypt any amount of data (since AES is strong)
- `user1` can encrypt data, `user2` can get them (steal), and now `user2` can decrypt the data of `user1` using the oracle
- since I provide an oracle, I have little concerns of timing attacks and padding attacks

What are the risk, attacks and holes I am missing in this scheme ?

Comment: Will you _actually have_ cleartext (aka [header / associated data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption)), as opposed to just plaintext?

Comment: I am not sure what your are talking about. In my current implementation, users send only the data they want to be encrypted, with no type of authentification.

Comment: So, you'll have plaintext but no cleartext.

Comment: Don't forget replay attacks, don't allow reuse of requests